# Error message in SQL Server 2012 Import Wizard

Tags: sql-server

I was trying to load an Excel file into SQL Server 2012 and got the following error.

[image: Error image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2Mut.png)

Error message 1:

### TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard

An error occurred which the SQL Server Integration Services Wizard was not prepared to handle.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A generic error occurred in GDI+. (System.Drawing)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Technical detail 1:

===================================

An error occurred which the SQL Server Integration Services Wizard was not prepared to handle. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

===================================

A generic error occurred in GDI+. (System.Drawing)

---

Program Location:

```
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(String text, Font font, RectangleF layoutRect, StringFormat stringFormat)
   at System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.EnsureRun(Graphics g)
   at System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Label.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.WndProc(Message& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Error Message 2:

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server

This wizard will close because it encountered the following error:

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=12.0.4100.1&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.WizardFrameworkErrorSR&EvtID=UncaughtException&LinkId=20476

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A generic error occurred in GDI+. (System.Drawing)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Technical detail 2:

===================================

This wizard will close because it encountered the following error: (Microsoft SQL Server)

---

## For help, click:  See link above (I cannot post 2 links)

A generic error occurred in GDI+. (System.Drawing)

---

Program Location:

```
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString(String text, Font font, SizeF layoutArea, StringFormat stringFormat)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Label.GetPreferredSizeCore(Size proposedConstraints)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.GetPreferredSize(Size proposedSize)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Label.GetPreferredSize(Size proposedSize)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Layout.TableLayout.GetElementSize(IArrangedElement element, Size proposedConstraints)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Layout.TableLayout.InflateColumns(ContainerInfo containerInfo, Size proposedConstraints, Boolean measureOnly)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Layout.TableLayout.ApplyStyles(ContainerInfo containerInfo, Size proposedConstraints, Boolean measureOnly)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Layout.TableLayout.LayoutCore(IArrangedElement container, LayoutEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Layout.LayoutEngine.Layout(Object container, LayoutEventArgs layoutEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs levent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs levent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel.OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs levent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformLayout(LayoutEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformLayout()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ResumeLayout(Boolean performLayout)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ResumeLayout()
   at Microsoft.NetEnterpriseServers.ExceptionMessageBoxForm.AddAdditionalInfoMessage(Int32 messageCount, String strText, Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.NetEnterpriseServers.ExceptionMessageBoxForm.InitializeMessage()
   at Microsoft.NetEnterpriseServers.ExceptionMessageBoxForm.PrepareToShow()
   at Microsoft.NetEnterpriseServers.ExceptionMessageBox.Show(IWin32Window owner)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.DtsWizard.DTSWizard.DisplayExceptionMessageBox(String errorMessage, Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.DtsWizard.Step1.OnLeavePage(LeavePageEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.WizardPage.RaiseLeavePage(WizardButton button)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.WizardForm.NextPage(WizardPage nextPage)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.WizardForm.Next_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: Post the error *text* in the question itself, not a picture that *doesn't* show the error.

Comment: The dialog box actually shows copy and exception buttons in the lower left corner. Use them to copy the error message and post it in the question

Comment: Looks like nothing to do with the actual data. Reboot the (client!) machine first, it may be out of resources. If that doesn't help, try a repair reinstall of Management Studio (or just [download the latest version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms), it supports SQL Server 2012).